# Javascript localstorage condition not responding

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am testing to see if a localstorage key exists or not.

So first I've done a console.log to see what's inside the value...

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('mykey'));
```

This returns `null`

So I've done this for a condition:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('mykey') === null) {
    console.log('It is null');
}
```

But although I know it's null it's not showing:

```
console.log('It is null');
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: I can reproduce this by setting the item to `"null"`, since `"null"` is a string and different from `null`.

Comment: Simply do `if (!localStorage.getItem('mykey')) {...}`

Comment: I mean't "null" without the quotes ... I'll edit the question

Comment: You've run `setItem('mykey', ...)` during testing, now the key exists.

Comment: run something like this before localStorage.setItem('mykey','crapycode');

Comment: Also you should know that localstorage is slow

Comment: @Melchia slow compare to ?

Comment: How about use `if('mykey' in localStorage)  {...}`?

Comment: It takes time to make CRUD operations with localstorage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677373/can-localstorage-slow-down-my-website-when-used-frequently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated*

*The original posted `localStorage.getItem('mykey') === null` actually returns `true` on Chrome, so it might be a browser related issue.*

*So by using the first suggested solution with double equal `==`, one might get a better crossbrowser support, though the 2nd/3rd options might be even better.*

<strike>If the key doesn't exist, the returned value is an `object` being `null`, which is not the *exact same type (`===`)* as `null`</strike>

Either drop one `=` (and it will do an auto-cast) and it will work

```
if (localStorage.getItem('mykey') == null) {
  console.log('It is null');
}
```

or simply do something like e.g.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('mykey')) {
  console.log('It is null');
}
```

or ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41462498/2827823)) which might be even better (and could be a dupe actually)

```
if (!localStorage.hasOwnProperty('mykey')) {
  console.log('It is null');
}
```

Comment: I don't think the first suggestion is correct. `localStorage.getItem('randomkey') === null` is true (tested on Chromium 66)

Comment: @AurélienBottazini With Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) it also returns true ... hmmm, will update my answer, as it appears this might be a browser issue then. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @AurélienBottazini Updated my answer with something that might be more appropiate.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `localStorage.setItem('someKey', null)` and then if you will try get and check `someKey` value like this `localStorage.getItem('someKey') === null` comparison result will `false` you need use `JSON.parse()` method before comparison with `null` like this `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someKey')) === null`

Answer (score 0):

Check if localStorage is null.If localStorage  is null the control won't enter the if block.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesis on what is happening:

```
localStorage.setItem('mykey', null)
console.log(localStorage.getItem('mykey')) // returns "null"
```

So explicitly setting `mykey` to null actually sets it to the `"null"` string.

For that comparaison to work you could do

```
if (localStorage.getItem('mykey') === 'null') {
  console.log('It is null');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The identity (===) operator checks whether both the operands are equal or identical in both value and datatype. That is,

```
var a = 2;
if (a === '2')
```

- will return false, since a is integer and '2' is a string. Where as,

```
if (a == 2)
```

- will return true, since '==' operator doen't enforce datatype eqality.

So in order to handle all situations like, the key is missing from localStorage or it is explicitly set to null, you should use '==' operator.