# Using async or not in javascript localStorage function

Tags: javascript, performance, local-storage

I have this small javascript function to set dark or light theme to localStorage:

```
const theme = (() => {
    if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem('theme')) {
      return localStorage.getItem('theme');
    }
    if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
      return 'dark';
    }
    return 'light';
  })();

  if (theme === 'light') {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
  } else {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
  }

  window.localStorage.setItem('theme', theme!);

  const handleToggleClick = () => {
    const element = document.documentElement;
    element.classList.toggle('dark');

    const isDark = element.classList.contains('dark');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', isDark ? 'dark' : 'light');
  };

  const element = document.getElementById('jsThemeToggle');

  if (element !== null) {
    element.addEventListener('click', handleToggleClick);
  }
```

Is it better to create an `async` function to have any performance benefit or something else?

Comment: 1. there is no `theme()` function, 2. there's nothing asynchronous in the IIFE that returns a value to `theme` so making it `async` won't make any positive impact on "performance"

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous about the code, why would you mark it as `async`? And how do expect to get a performance benefit from this?

Comment: @Bergi @Jaromanda if you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677373/can-localstorage-slow-down-my-website-when-used-frequently#:~:text=Local%20storage%20stores%20the%20data,when%20the%20user%20logs%20out). Isn't it better to make my localStorage `async`? Somebody is saying that the IIFE function won't block the thread when making it async?

Comment: @meez I don't see how `async`/`await` is at all related to the linked question. It only talks about possibly optimising multiple read/write operations. Is that the case you have? And even if so, how is `async` supposed to help?

Comment: @meez — You can’t make localStorage asynchronous (which is not the same as `async`), it’s built into the browser, you can’t edit its source code. (Well, there open source browsers, so technically you can … but that it wouldn’t be compatible with the **standard** and every website you visited with your custom browser that depended on it would break. (You can’t make it `async` either because it isn’t written in JS in the first place, it just has an API exposed to JS)

Comment: @meez That question asks about "*updating localStorage properties frequently*", which is not what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `async` keyword is to allow the use of the `await` keyword inside the function. (As a side effect `async` causes that function to return a promise).

You have no promises to manage with the `await` keyword, so adding the `async` keyword would be pointless.